# How do I avoid recalculating in Swift extensions?

Tags: swift

I have the following extension for Color.
How do I avoid recalculating the `components` part?

```
extension Color {
    
    var cgColor: CGColor {
        resolve(in: .init()).cgColor
    }
    
    var r: Int {
        guard let components = cgColor.components, components.count == 4 else {
            return 0
        }
        return Int(components[0] * 256)
    }
    
    var g: Int {
        guard let components = cgColor.components, components.count == 4 else {
            return 0
        }
        return Int(components[1] * 256)
    }
    
    var b: Int {
        guard let components = cgColor.components, components.count == 4 else {
            return 0
        }
        return Int(components[2] * 256)
    }
    
    var a: Double {
        guard let components = cgColor.components, components.count == 4 else {
            return 1
        }
        return components[3]
    }
    
}
```

I have tried storing a `var` in the places utilising the color. However I would like a way to do it within the extension.

Comment: What's wrong with "recalculating" `components`?

Comment: You are resolving the color against the default environment values, not the current environment. This means the RGB values would not adapt to the current environment.